# HTML Table Vertical Scroll with first column frozen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, internet-explorer, html-table

I am using [React Bootstrap (v4)](https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/components/table/) Table.

I want to have a frozen first column with x & y scroll which should be IE11 compatible.

I tried adding `position: absolute` to first column, but it does not scroll vertically. Adding `position: relative` to the table parent removes the frozen capabilities.

Here is a basic implementation of what I'm trying to do. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshvarun/1y3Ljgwp/4/)

HTML:

```
<div><table>
    <tr><td class="headcol">1</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="headcol">2</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="headcol">3</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="headcol">4</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="headcol">5</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="headcol">6</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="headcol">7</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="headcol">8</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="headcol">9</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
<tr><td class="headcol">10</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
<tr><td class="headcol">11</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
<tr><td class="headcol">12</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
<tr><td class="headcol">13</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
<tr><td class="headcol">14</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
```

CSS:

```
        body { font:16px Calibri;}
    table { border-collapse:separate; border-top: 3px solid grey; }
    td {
        margin:0;
        border:3px solid grey; 
        border-top-width:0px; 
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    div { 
        width: 600px; 
        overflow-x:scroll;  
        margin-left:5em; 
        overflow-y:visible;
        padding-bottom:1px;
height: 200px;
    }
    .headcol {
        position:absolute; 
        width:5em; 
        left:0;
        top:auto;
        border-right: 0px none black; 
        border-top-width:3px; /*only relevant for first row*/
        margin-top:-3px; /*compensate for top border*/
    }
    .headcol:before {content: 'Row ';}
    .long { letter-spacing:1em; }
```

How can I achieve this without using `position: sticky` and without `jQuery`?

Comment: You better add code so we can fix and test.

Comment: @BehradHajmiri Added code, apologies.